# react-native-qrcode-svg not working on eas build

Tags: android, react-native, svg, expo, eas

I just created a new react-native expo app.

I installed a few dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "qrcode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "46.0.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.3.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.2.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am running on eas build instead of using the expo go app.
I am trying to use the [`react-native-qrcode-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-qrcode-svg) package but it doesn't work

I always keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: _qrcode.default.create is not a function. (In '_qrcode.default.create(value, {
      errorCorrectionLevel: errorCorrectionLevel
    })', '_qrcode.default.create' is undefined)
```

I am extremely surprised of the lack of solution or direction to solve this error on the internet. I have never come across the anything like this tbh lol.

Please what could be the problem or a possible solution?